Translations are not imported
I'm automating an upgrade of a site and in various phase of the import, setup, and configuration of that new site (to latest Drupal 9, then further upgraded to Drupal 10). I do several drush config:export just to be safe.
This site has several custom content types, with no module associated. It just uses the Field module from Drupal core.
I ended up with a language/xx subdir that actually contains some field label translations.
So, in the main config dir I may end up with a field.field.node.NODE_TYPE.FIELD_NAME.yml and a corresponding language/XX/field.field.node.NODE_TYPE.FIELD_NAME.yml with just the label defined.
When I run drush config:import --yes --partial --source=/CONFIGDIR, translations aren't imported. drush cr doesn't help.

Remove --partial and --source. Configure source in settings.php. What happens when you export? What happens when you change the label in that language file before import?

Which translations are not imported?  The UI translations are exported with drush locale:export, not config:export.

If something in config is “not imported”, that should imply that the target storage already matched the source storage, so there was nothing to do. It may have already been achieved by, for example, installing a module. Have you confirmed that’s not the case?

Adding some details. Structure->Content type -> pick my content type -> Manage field -> pick one field Translate -> Edit -> change something (label/help text) -> drush drush config:export. Check in the exported config there is a language/xx/that actually INCLUDE the change. Delete the whole site, recreate it (up to the point the translation was NOT modified), drush config:import the whole exported dir, translation of that field DON'T get imported. @PatrickKenny I'd try locale:export but why on earth I can config:export translations if I can not config:import them?

@HumbleProgrammer config:export translations can be imported with config:import; my comment was that not all translations are exported as config.  After config:import, have the languages been created properly?  (Can you see them on the language admin page?)

@PatrickKenny what I find puzzling is you edit a field label translation, the edit show up in the nodes (after drush cr), you config:export, find the edit in the language/XX/field.field....yaml, revert back to the site before the edit (let's say restore the DB before the edit), config:import, drush cr BUT you can't find the edit in the admin interface nor the field label get translated in the node. I'm going to try with locale:export, but this behavior I described is misleading or unnecessary or wrong.

This is speaking from memory, but the language has to be created before the import works.  So I have had to run config import multiple times consecutively in the past to get everything imported.  This is a special case that only occurs when the language doesn't already exist in the db.

SOLVED
It seems that during import Drupal sees the change only if the MAIN yaml associated to the field is updated.

backup the DB
Say you've a field.field.node.NODE_TYPE.FIELD_NAME.yml
You config:export (will save the MAIN definition of the field)
/config1/...
Add translations
config:export again (will only save the translations) /config2/languages/...
restore the DB to 1
config:import config1
config:import config2

Translations won't be imported
To actually import translations you've to merge /config2/ into /config1/ copying /config2/language into /config1/
Merging /config1/ into /config2/ DOESN'T work
Once the main field has been imported, if it remains the same but translations are added, translations won't be imported.
